# Ignore whitespaces inside of a table

Tags: tables

I would like to eliminate blank parts of a table. Here is my LaTeX snippet:

```
\documentclass[english,a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{changepage}

\begin{document}

\clearpage
\begin{table}[ht]
\begin{adjustwidth}{-3.7cm}{}
\begin{tabular}{|p{.6\textwidth}|p{.75\textwidth}|}
\hline
{\begin{lstlisting}[basicstyle={\scriptsize\ttfamily},
identifierstyle={\color{black}},
tabsize=2,language={Java},
numbersep=8pt,numbers=left,xleftmargin=0.5cm,frame=tlbr,framesep=2pt,framerule=0pt,
morekeywords={class,run}]
class PrintHelloThread ext Thread {
    void run(Dummy x) {
        out.println("Hello world")
    }
}
class X ext ProxifiedObject {
    PrintHelloThread thread
    void main(X x) {
        x.thread := new PrintHelloThread;
        x.thread.start(0);
        x.thread.join(0);
    }
}
\end{lstlisting}}
&
{\begin{lstlisting}[
basicstyle={\scriptsize\ttfamily},
identifierstyle={\color{black}},
tabsize=2,
language={Java},
numbersep=8pt,
numbers=left,
xleftmargin=0.5cm,frame=tlbr,framesep=2pt,framerule=0pt,
morekeywords ={class,run}
]
class PrintHelloThread ext Thread {
    void run(Dummy x) {
        out.println("Hello world")
    }
}
class X ext ProxifiedObject {
    PrintHelloThread thread
    void main(X x) {
        x.thread := new PrintHelloThread;
        x.thread.start(0);
        x.thread.join(0);
    }
}
\end{lstlisting}}
\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{adjustwidth}
\caption{\label{fig:text}text experiment ent experiment experiment}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You can reduce the column size in `{|p{.6\textwidth}|p{.75\textwidth}|}` Is that what you want?

Comment: The table only has so much white space as you specified the second column to be very wide `|p{.6\textwidth}|p{.75\textwidth}|}`

Comment: what if I have a large code snippet and need to set textwidth as .8?

Comment: If your text is wider, how can you hope to miss out the space at the end of the (shorter) lines?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to refine the whitespace of the table, I have found a quick way to do that. First inside of the table there are two listings so that if the following commands `aboveskip,belowskip` are used in these listings' properties, below and above empty spaces are gone.

```
\documentclass[english,a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{changepage}

\begin{document}

\clearpage
\begin{table}[ht]
\begin{adjustwidth}{-3.7cm}{}
\begin{tabular}{|p{.6\textwidth}|p{.75\textwidth}|}
\hline
{\begin{lstlisting}[basicstyle={\scriptsize\ttfamily},aboveskip=-8pt,belowskip=-10pt,
identifierstyle={\color{black}},
tabsize=2,language={Java},
numbersep=8pt,numbers=left,xleftmargin=0.5cm,frame=tlbr,framesep=2pt,framerule=0pt,
morekeywords={class,run}]
class PrintHelloThread ext Thread {
    void run(Dummy x) {
        out.println("Hello world")
    }
}
class X ext ProxifiedObject {
    PrintHelloThread thread
    void main(X x) {
        x.thread := new PrintHelloThread;
        x.thread.start(0);
        x.thread.join(0);
    }
}
\end{lstlisting}}
&
{\begin{lstlisting}[
basicstyle={\scriptsize\ttfamily},aboveskip=-8pt,belowskip=-10pt,
identifierstyle={\color{black}},
tabsize=2,
language={Java},
numbersep=8pt,
numbers=left,
xleftmargin=0.5cm,frame=tlbr,framesep=2pt,framerule=0pt,
morekeywords ={class,run}
]
class PrintHelloThread ext Thread {
    void run(Dummy x) {
        out.println("Hello world")
    }
}
class X ext ProxifiedObject {
    PrintHelloThread thread
    void main(X x) {
        x.thread := new PrintHelloThread;
        x.thread.start(0);
        x.thread.join(0);
    }
}
\end{lstlisting}}
\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{adjustwidth}
\caption{\label{fig:text}text experiment ent experiment experiment}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Here is the result:
[image]